# an inside numbered list-style causing layout issue when content is block in non-WebKit browsers

Tags: css

I have a design on my blog that uses the following CSS to number a list:

```
list-style: decimal inside none;
```

Inside each `<li>` element is an anchor tag that is displayed block. In WebKit browsers this works just fine. In FireFox, IE, and Opera the display of the inner block anchor is pushed down by the width of the list-style. I've tried to play with padding, margins, and text-indent to fix it, but I'm having no luck. I can't style them outside, because I want to change the left border color of the LI for the selected element. I could position the anchor tag to absolute and position it right, but I feel there is a simple fix here that I am missing.

Anybody have a solution for fixing the CSS to work in non-WebKit browsers?

Here is the site, see the menu on the right:
http://mattsnider.com/styleguide/html/

All CSS Applied to LI:

```
.menu .menu-item:first-child {
    border-top: 0 none;
}
.menu-numbered .menu-item {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
}
.menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

All CSS Applied to Anchor:

```
.menu-item.selected a {
    border-left-color: black;
}
.menu-item a {
    border-left: 2px solid #FAFAFB;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1em;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 8px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
.l_aside a {
    color: #3D49FF;
}
a {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: WebKit seems to be the one doing it wrong according to the spec... can you list the complete CSS rules that you're applying to the list, as well as the markup?

Comment: That's fine, do you know the CSS to make it behave like WebKit in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's a 13 year old bug...nice find! noted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position   documentation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854

you have options here....you could set the anchor to `display:inline-block` and fiddle with `text-align`, and `text-indent`, while swapping your selected border to the list element. hard to tell entirely, but those options do work for me in firefox.